# How to use textFieldShouldReturn method as selector action?

Tags: ios, objective-c

On the right is picker view toolbar button 'Next' and want to call `textFieldShouldReturn` method on its action via `@selector`. But it gives me error `Undeclared Selector`.
This is button's code,

```
 UIBarButtonItem *nextBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector("textFieldShouldReturn here")];
```

And this is my textFieldShouldReturn method,

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
self.addScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1800);
[self.addScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 ) animated:NO];

 if (textField == industryTxtField) {
    [subIndustryTxtField becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if (textField == subIndustryTxtField) {
    [address1TxtField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpHAG.png)

Comment: What gives you error, the button declaration or the function? where are you calling the function?

Comment: once check how many curly braces you opened and closed, and that method expecting a return value (Bool value), what you have returned ?

Comment: The button declaration gives me warning "Undeclared selector textfieldShouldReturn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this ...

```
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(moveToNextField)];

-(void)moveToNextField
{
  if (industryTxtField.isFirstResponder) 
  {
    [subIndustryTxtField becomeFirstResponder];
  }
  else if (subIndustryTxtField.isFirstResponder) 
  {
    [address1TxtField becomeFirstResponder];
  }

}
```